# photoshop workflow: after action ran, make early step revisable?

Tags: workflow

I often want to make my workflow revisable -  I often go back to an early step and change it, and, often with help of Smart Object if later layers are NOT all adjusting layer, I could pass that change to later layers, thus add least extra workload.

Now I need help with a specific situation: say I pack the following steps into an Action: copy a channel, High Pass, Apply Image 3 times boosting contrast. All in a Smart Object, so workflow is revisable.

After this Action ran, I go back and change High Pass value, now: I want those 3 Apply Image changed correspondingly and automatically, question is: how can I achieve this?

I know I could replace 3 Apply Image steps with one curve, but sometimes it's subtle, and this question is also about method, I could use this method, if any, to other situations.

Comment: Apply Image will create a mask for the adjustments on a Smart Object, and so it's destructive at the mask level. I think you'd be better to use non-destructive adjustments instead if you want to edit them later. What is the effect you are actually trying to achieve? Could you share an image?

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks for your help. I think I got a method: instead of using 3 Apply Image on a channel, I do not use channel, I work on smart object LAYER (can be revised in future), then create one any adjusting layer, mode is Hard Light (same as in Apply Image), copy this layer several times. In future's revise, just hiding some of these copies would do the trick.